Gambler ruin's: Probability of $k$ consecutive win before j consecutive loss
Assume that a stock has a probability of $p$ to win, a probability of $q$ to lose, and a probability of $(1-p-q)$ to remain every day. What is the probability of $k$ consecutive wins occur before $j$ consecutive loses?
I am trying come up with a martingale to solve it. Denote $\tau:\min\{t > 0: X_{t} \text{ contains $k$ consecutive wins or $j$ consecutive loss}\},$ where $X_{t}$ is the total money at the time $t.$ I am stuck on how to construct this martingale. Any hints would be helpful!

This is too vague.  Every possiblle sequence will occur with probability $1$ if you wait long enough.

In short, the problem is what is the probability of k consecutive wins occurs before j consecutive loses?

That's different from the original question.  To do this one, you have a messy Markov problem.  Use states counting the string of consecutive winners.

Denote $P_{i}$ as the probability of k consecutive wins before j consecutive loss when there are i consecutive wins before? -j means there are j consecutive loss before.

Yes, I get the question,  The way the original was phrased, I thought you wanted a block of the form $W^kL^j$ which is a very different question.

This method will result in a messy Markov problem. I am wondering if there is a martingale method solve it easily. Thanks for your kind help!

Messy Markov is what you have, I fear.  Maybe broader questions would be interesting...like, for a given $p$, describe the equiprobable boundary (the pairs $(k,j)$ for which the answer is $\frac 12$).  That might be answerable, not sure.

Can you give me State transfer equation for this question?  Does this $ P_{-b + 1} = p P_{-b} + q P_{-b + 2}, ... , P_{0} = p P_{-1} + q P_{1}$ right?

Not sure of your notation.  To me, the states are of the form $\pm i$ where $+i$ means that you have $i$ wins in a row, and $-i$ means that you have $i$ losses in a row.  Then the transition probabilities are clear.  $(+i)\mapsto +(i+1)$ or to $-(1)$ with clear probabilities.

I see. $(+i) \to  (i+1)$ with probability $p, \to  (-1)$ with probability $q, \to (0)$ with probability $1-p-q$. Thanks!

Clarification requested: If the stock goes up on day 1, stays the same on day 2, and then goes up on day 3, does this count as two consecutive wins?  Alternatively, does the break even on day 2 interrupt the streak that began on day 1?

I think so. even breaks the consecutive.

Maybe the Markov approach can be simplified. You have 5 states: $S$, $+$, $-$, $W$, $L$, with $P(+|S) = p$, $P(-|S) = q$, $P(W|+) = p^{k-1}$, $P(-|+) = 1-p^{k-1}$, $P(L|-) = q^{j-1}$, $P(+|-)=1-q^{j-1}$, with the assumption that $p+q=1$. $S$ is the starting state.

I am concerned about the term "consecutive". Usually in this kinds of problems, one asks for winning k times before loosing j times without insisting on the order or wins and losses. That indeed would be a simple version of the Gambler's ruin and easy to solve with martingales.
